# Why does windows 7 shutdown require so much hard drive usage?

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, shutdown

When I shut down linux, for example, it takes a couple seconds. All it does is shut down running services, maybe write a couple log files etc... On my windows 7 box however it takes about 1 minute to shut down and the hdd i/o light is completely lit.

Is windows 7 writing a lot of log files or is something else going on when I shut down? Also, does this happen for linux based oses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem with Windows 7. It's a problem with how you've maintained your PC. Mine takes around 5 seconds to shut down (Windows 7 64-bit).

Open Task Manager and see what services and processes are running. I bet if you use MSTSC to disable the bulk of your unnecessary background tasks, you'll see a massive performance increase.

I only have my antivirus (Microsoft Security Essentials), and F.lux (automatically sets screen brightness levels depending on time of day) run when my PC starts- no need for anything else. The majority of people only need antivirus to run on system start.

If you've got a bloated antivirus program (Norton/AVG etc.) that will add a few seconds to shutdown.

Comment: I do have a lot of services running. Why do these write to the disk upon shut down though?

Comment: Depends on the program, but in general they need time to gracefully close first (i.e. write data from memory to disk to preserve their state).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it also takes a bit longer to log off and subsequently shut down if your computer is connected to a domain network.

Comment: In particular, it will synchronize your roaming profile with the [PDC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_Domain_Controller), so if you have a huge amount of data in `\Users\username\AppData\Roaming`, it can take a *really* long time.

Comment: Yes- this should only be an issue when roaming profiles are used.

Domain PCs which are not using roaming profiles should be just as fast to log off/shut down as non-domain PCs (and are, in my experience).